Do They Make Two-Way/Three-way Adjustable Hinges for Front Doors
I am putting in a new front door.  I'd like to use hinges that would allow me to adjust door in two, or better, three planes/axes.  They make something like this for cabinet doors (see image; I get that style/engineering is not what one would expect to see in a front door hinge), and I was hoping there was a more heavy-duty one available for large or heavy exterior door applications?


I doubt it.  Most doors do not need to be adjustable.  You adjust the door frame to be square and plumb and everything else should just fit.

@crip659: I think I managed to find what I was looking for (blind squirrel syndrome!)  I jimmied with some of my search terms and got a better 1st page of hits, finally, so I am going to delete this thread in a few, since the only issue at this point was my trial-and-error Googling.

Feel free to post and accept an answer. It's not a bad question.

One of the hits I found displayed below.  I assume there are others and will do a little more investigating, esp. to see if there are other styles (e.g. square corner profiles) and sizes available.
Hoppe Adjustable Hinge 3-1/2" x 3-1/2"

